# Laravel: catch route not defined exception in API

Tags: laravel, api, exception, methods, try-catch

I think this question may sound crazy to some people...

Is it possible to catch the `Route not defined` exception while making an api request and return a decent response instead of receiving a blown up response from the application itself..?

For example: I have a route in the `api.php` called `Route::post('/validate-mobile', 'Api\ComeController@validateMobile')` which must be accessed via the `POST` method and the developer is trying to access it via `GET`, `PUT` or any other method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can : in `Handler` ( `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` ) write code in `render()` method

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) { // for 404
      // do stuff
    }
    if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) { // for checking  api method
      // do stuff
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Use this line above :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```

Comment: Sorry, @YasinPatel this did not work. I am getting this error `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException`

Comment: Use this line above : use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;

Comment: also this : use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

Answer (score 1):

*1 go to App\Exceptions\Handler.php*

*2 change the render function and remove the parent render function and instead return your own json response, like in this gist:*

```
  <?php
    namespace App\Exceptions;
    use Exception;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
    class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
    {
        /**
         * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $dontReport = [
            //
        ];
        /**
         * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $dontFlash = [
            'password',
            'password_confirmation',
        ];
        /**
         * Report or log an exception.
         *
         * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
         *
         * @param  \Exception  $exception
         * @return void
         */
        public function report(Exception $exception)
        {
            parent::report($exception);
        }
        /**
         * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Exception  $exception
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function render($request, Exception $exception)
        {
            return response()->json(
                [
                    'errors' => [
                        'status' => 401,
                        'message' => 'Unauthenticated',
                    ]
                ], 401
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this and it work however, this will be defined for all the exception. Isn't there any other way..?

Comment: if you get your answer please select my answer and please give upvote..thank you..

Comment: Sorry @PHP, I have accepted the YasinPatel's answer